# Unable to find team Id in apple developer account

Tags: ios

I am trying to build my first app on IOS. So I was added a team member by my organization and I was given admin role.

I am able to see that in applestoreconnect page that I fall under specific team

But when I go to developer.apple.com I don't find any membership details where I can find a team Id.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uDxg.png) Here if you can it shows I am added as a team member.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36fp3.png) Here in my developer account it doesn't list any membership information

Comment: On first image (itunesconnect.com), click on your name that is top right corner. And then View profile. You can see your team ID there.